# jQuery replace string if its a double space or a single space

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have strings coming into my javascript the variations can be..
`Foo  Bar` 
(double space) 
or 
`Foo Bar`

I currently have this working out if it has a single space, replace with an underscore

```
var string = 'John Doe';
var fixedString = string.replace(/\s+/, "_");

$('#display').text(fixedString);
```

But I want to be able to do this if it is a double space also..

As a result `Foo  Bar` would be fixed to `Foo__Bar`

Comment: ```string.replace(/[ ][ ]/g, '__');```

Comment: yourstring.replace(/[' ']+/g, "_")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use slug utility function

```
function convertToSlug(str) {
    return str.replace(/ /g,'_');
}
```

Demo below

```js
var text = 'Foo  Bar,Single Space,Many        Spaces'

//from https://gist.github.com/vko-online/4c7699a78e48963310ae
function convertToSlug(str) {
    return str.replace(/ /g,'_');
}

var $orig = document.querySelector('#orig'),
    $slug = document.querySelector('#slug');

$orig.textContent = text; //although text has 2 spaces, h1 tag remove 1
$slug.textContent = convertToSlug(text);
```

```html
<h1 id="orig"></h1>
<h1 id="slug"></h1>
```

Comment: But what is the purpose of using `.replace(/[^\w-]+/g,'')` with OP's case?

Comment: I need to be able to use an if to replace either one space, or two spaces.

Comment: @A.Wolff yeah, it just removes `-` dashes, it was intended by author, just removed it

Comment: @Kieron606 it works with 1 or 2 or infinity spaces, `Foo  Bar` in example has 2 spaces

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

`yourstring.replace(/[' ']+/g, "_")`

```
var string = 'John      Doe';
string1 = "John doe"


string.replace(/[' ']+/g, "_"); //'John_Doe'
string1.replace(/[' ']+/g, "_"); //'John_Doe'
```

OR if you want to replace every space with one `_` then use this one

```
string.replace(/[' ']/g, "_");
```